# Display number of ("child" activity's) checked items in a listview item of parent activity

Tags: android, listview

This is for Android.

First of all, an example of what I have in mind:

[image: Camping trip planner example]

How could I achieve this effect? This listview's items display the number of unchecked items in the child listview that opens up when you click one of the parent listviews's items. Should I use a static class for the child activity? Or as many instances as there are rows in the first listview? Could someone provide me with an example? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Just make a method for calculating total/checked number of items and save the result as a two static values.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Where should the method be (which class, parent or child)?  Should it be void or should it return anything? And where should the static values be stored, in the parent class? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slickelito, thanks for your answer, I learned a few stuff about abstract classes but in the end I came across my own solution:

I made my own cursor adapter and this method -

```
public int getChildCount(long lvPhase) {
    String phase = Long.toString(lvPhase);
    String[] projection = { FlightBundleDatabase.ID };
    String[] selectionArgs = { Long.toString(mAircraft), phase };
    int count = 0;

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(mContext, FlightBundleProvider.CONTENT_URI_CHECKLISTS, projection, "aircraft_id = ? AND phase = ?", selectionArgs, null);
    Cursor cursor = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();
    int cCount = cursor.getCount();
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
        for (int i = 0; i < cCount; i++) {
            long currentItem = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(FlightBundleDatabase.ID));
            if (mSettingsActivity.contains(phase + currentItem)) {
                count++;
                }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return count;
}
```

And then I bound the counter TextView text to this method's return value. It seems to work, although I'm not totally sure about efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a model called something like Tasks.

Make an abstract class called something like ProgressCounter.
Setup two static values :

```
 public static int totalNumberOfTasks;
 public static int taskProgress;
```

Then you make a static method and iterate over it :

```
public static void countProgress(ArrayList<Tasks> allTasks){
 ProgressCounter.totalNumberOfTasks = allTask.size();
 int taskProgress = 0;
   for(Task task : allTasks){
   if(task.isCompleted());
   taskProgress++;
 }
 ProgressCounter.taskProgress = taskProgress;
 }
```

I hope this can point you in the right direction :)

Comment: Hmm, looks promising :). I'll give it a shot tomorrow and of course approve your answer if it solves my problem. Either way, thanks a lot.